# How properly add C# code to a PowerShell script?

Tags: .net, powershell

```
$w=@'
using System;
using System.Drawing;

public class img{
    public static String test(){
        Image image = Image.FromFile("C:\\img.png");
        String size = image.Width+"x"+image.Height;
        return size;
    }
}
'@

add-type -typed $w
[img]::test()
```

I wand to add this c# code, but i got error. How to properly add c# code?

Comment: It is a best practice to [edit] the question and include the error messages - as text, no images - to the question body. The errors often contain important clues about what might be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the C# code uses System.Drawing, one must tell `Add-Type` where it comes from.

Add-Type has [-ReferencedAssemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-7) parameter that does exactly that. Like so,

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $w -ReferencedAssemblies System.Drawing
```